# How to sort list of jobs by submitted time/job name?

Tags: cluster-computing, batch-processing, lsf

In LAVA or LSF, how to sort the output of *bjobs* command by submitted time/job name?
Bare *bjobs* usually gives a mess. I cannot find the right option in manuals, e.g., in [this one](http://www.openlava.org/documentation/man1/bjobs.1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an option to sort bjobs' output by time or job name. You could manually parse the specific column. 
Depending on what information you are interested in... you can look into bjobs -r, -p, -u flags.

Comment: It *does* provide an answer to the question.  The answer is *it can't be done*.